# What are the benefits and drawbacks of running a UniKernel?

Tags: linux

What are the Benefits of running a UniKernel. Isn't it more work to coordinate multiple UniKernels spinning up and down versus the traditional application?

What pieces of Software will be rewritten using a UniKernel, where does it make sense?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel#Benefits_and_drawbacks